# what does "s-f" means in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

Some of the emacs keys are rebound in spacemacs. I saw this in emacs tutorial

** C-s has been rebound, but you can use s-f instead [More] **

what does s-f here means? It can't be character `s` followed by character `f`.

Answer (score 0):

See [EmacsKeyNotation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsKeyNotation):

> `S-`
>   means the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (e.g. `S-TAB` means <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

Comment: The `s` in my context definitely can't be just the shift key either: because `s-f` would then just insert a capital letter `F` to current buffer. I found the answer accidentally. The said "s-f" command can be executed by command-shift-f (macs).